# Azure App Service with Python 3.9 deployment failed

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, glibc

We are trying to deploy a rather simple flask app to azure app service. The deployment (using local git) fails with the following output:

```
remote: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9
remote: Creating directory for command manifest file if it doesnot exist
remote: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
remote: Removing existing manifest file
remote: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
remote: Python Virtual Environment: antenv
remote: Creating virtual environment...
remote: Deployment Failed.
```

Anyone there that has an idea why this fails? It should be so simple.... :(
It is an app service, not a docker container, not a vm..

Greets,
John

Comment: I have the same issue! Losing my sanity on the cause of the failure. If anyone finds the solution please share

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781592/vs-code-azure-deployment-of-python-http-trigger-function-fails-glib-2-27-not-f/71783107#71783107

Comment: I downgraded python 3.9 to 3.8 in the settings of the service app (runtime settings). After that it worked again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error this morning and managed to fix it by changing the application's python version from 3.9 to 3.8.

I'm not quite sure why this is an issue now as previously I had the application deployed on python3.9.

In order to change your applications python version you need to

1. Go to the WebApp azure portal page
2. Select configuration on the left hand side of the page
3. Select General Settings
4. Change the Minor Version of python to 3.8 (I have not tested 3.7)

Hope this helps!

Comment: NOTE: It may be necessary to create a new commit depending on how you're deploying the application. I had to when deploying through VSCode's azure extension.

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked for me too. For context, my app was working fine in 3.9, but when I enabled Application Insights, the deployments started failing.  The full text of my error was `Deployment Failed. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip.`

Comment: Although this did not specifically work for me, I had found a way to read the logs that debug my service. One should log into https://<APP SERVICE NAME>i.scm.azurewebsites.net/ and view logs.